problems downloading static resource from apache
The resource is static file (archive.tar.gz) of approx 50MB served by apache 2.4.29 running on Ubuntu 18.04.3 with apache basic auth provided and pfsense 2.7.2 in front of apache.
sometimes download get locked, like this:
wget --debug https://example.org/archive.tar.gz
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.21.2 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/john/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'archive.tar.gz' (UTF-8) -> 'archive.tar.gz' (UTF-8)
--2024-06-12 11:30:20--  https://example.org/archive.tar.gz
Risoluzione di example.com (example.org)... [public ip]
Caching example.com => [public ip]
Connessione a example.com (example.org)|[public ip]|:443... connesso.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x000058810c8888d0 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
Handshake successful; connected socket 3 to SSL handle 0x000058810c88ad30
certificate:
  subject: CN=mydomain.com
  issuer:  CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
X509 certificate successfully verified and matches host mydomain.com

---request begin---
GET /archive.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain.com
User-Agent: Wget/1.21.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
Richiesta HTTP inviata, in attesa di risposta... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Wed, 12 Jun 2024 09:30:21 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
last-modified: Tue, 11 Jun 2024 12:05:22 GMT
etag: "36a149c-61a9c148b088e"
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 57283740
content-type: application/x-gzip

---response end---
200 OK
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Lunghezza: 57283740 (55M) [application/x-gzip]
Salvataggio in: ‘archive.tar.gz.12’

archive.tar.gz.12        8%[========>                                                                                                     ]   4,67M  --.-KB/s    in 80s     s


from pf-sense I saw no problems of any kind.
.htaccess for the resoruce folder is
AuthType Basic
AuthuserFile /var/htpasswd/credentials.txt
AuthName "PROTECTED"
require valid-user

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>


any advice?

Try directly to Apache HTTPD server instead of going through pf-sense to discard any issues with it.
